# Find subsequence of size k such that the minimum distance between values is maximum

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, approximation, np-hard

Suppose i have a *random* sequence(*ordering array*) which contain **n** positive float .
How to find subsequence of size **k** such that the minimum distance between all pairs of float in the subsequence is maximized , i mean they are at farthest distance .

**Note**: A *subsequence* of a sequence is an ordered subset of the sequence's elements having the same sequential ordering as the original sequence.

**CONSTRAINTS**

1. **n>10^5**
2. **n>k>2**

**example** :

sequence a[]={1.1,2.34,6.71,7.01,10.71} and k=3 ,
subsequence = {1.1,6.71,10.71} , the minimum distance is 4 between 10.71 and 6.71 .

**Wrong subsequence** :

{1.1,7.01,10.71} , minimum distance is 3.7

{1.1,2.34,6.71} , minimum distance is 1.24

I came up with a solution :

1) sort array

2) select a[0] , now find ceil(a[0]+ x) = Y in array ....and then ceil(Y+ x) and 
so on k-1 times , also kth element will be a[n-1]

To find x :

dp[i,j] be the x for selecting j elements from first i elements .

Finally we want dp[n][k] which is x

But i am facing problem in finding x and reordering the indexes.

dp[i,j] = max( min( dp[k,j-1], dp[i]-A[k] ) )

over k=1 to i-1 , i=2 to n , j=2 to i

dp[i][1] = 0 over i = 1 to n

I want to correct the dynamic programming solution , though i know x can be found out by binary searching over x , but by sorting i loose *ordering of sequence* and time consuming(**O**(**n^2**)).How do i overcome this problems?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution involving a sort, you first want to map the array to an array of tuples, which contain a value and a position of the element.  Now when you sort the array you know the original positions as well.

However I don't believe that sorting actually helps you in the end.

The approach that I see which works is for each `0 <= i < n`, for each `1 < j <= min(k, i+1)`, to store the minimum distance and previous entry for the best subsequence  of length `j` ending at `i`.

You then look for the best subsequence of length `k`.  And then decode the subsequence.

Using JSON notation (for clarity, and not because I this is the right data structure), and your example, you could wind up with a data structure like this:

```
[
    {"index": 0, "value": 1.1},
    {"index": 1, "value": 2.34,
        "seq": {2: {"dist": 1.34, "prev": 0}},
    {"index": 2, "value": 6.71,
        "seq": {2: {"dist": 5.61, "prev": 0},
                3: {"dist": 1.34, "prev": 1}},
    {"index": 3, "value": 7.01,
        "seq": {2: {"dist": 5.91, "prev": 0},
                3: {"dist": 1.34, "prev": 1}},
    {"index": 4, "value": 10.71,
        "seq": {2: {"dist": 9.61, "prev": 0},
                3: {"dist": 4, "prev": 2}}
]
```

And now we find that the biggest `dist` for length `3` is `3.7` at index `4`. Walking backwards we want index `4`, `2` and `0`.  Pull those out and reverse them to get the solution of `[1.1, 6.71, 10.71]`

Comment: OK... this is a good suggestion....but, it's time consuming...I,d like a greedily algorithm in O(n) rank

Comment: This solution is `O(k n^2)`.  With a lot of work it is possible to get this down to `O(k n log(n))`.  But I would recommend against trying to optimize it until after you have a working solution first.

Comment: @IrajShokouhiBahar Making sure that you actually saw the comment.  For the record I began trying to explain how to speed it up, but discovered quickly that it is complicated to explain.  It will be even more complicated to code.  I recommend against it.

Comment: Good... what do you recommend?

Comment: @IrajShokouhiBahar Try to get a solution working along the lines of what I described.  Obviously using more C-like data structures (like arrays of structs) rather than JSON.